# Multiple entries after storing one single certificate into my Java keystore

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, vcenter

I'm using the class [InstallCert](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-programatically-extract-a-certificate-from-a-site-and-add-it-to-my-keystore) to import a VMware vCenter certificate into my local Java keystore.

The line `socket.startHandshake()` returns an `UnsupportedOperationException`, but the class `SavingTrustManager` still has downloaded the certificate successfully.

Then I store the downloaded certificate into my local keystore by using the following snippet.

```
KeyStore jsk;
... ... ..
jks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jssecacert");
jks.store(out, passphrase);
out.close();
```

But when I try to list all the entries in the keystore: `keytool -list -keystore jssecacerts -v`, It shows that there are 160 entries including the one that I have downloaded.

I'm pretty sure that the keystore is generated by my code, and it is supposed to be initially empty. I'd like to know where do the other 159 entries come from ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use KeyStoreExplorer for comparing both truststores: jssecacerts generated by the Installcert class, and the cacerts file located en your Java>jre>security>lib.

Istallcert takes the certificate from the server and creates a copy of the truststore of the JVM you are using. then it adds the certificate to the copy of your truststore, and names it "jssecacerts". Check this piece of code:

```
File file = new File("jssecacerts");
    if (file.isFile() == false) {
        char SEP = File.separatorChar;
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP
        + "lib" + SEP + "security");
        file = new File(dir, "jssecacerts");
        if (file.isFile() == false) {
            file = new File(dir, "cacerts");

            }
    }
```

You then just need to rename jsscacerts to cacerts and replace the original one on your JVM

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in fact, the thing that confuses me is the number of entry in the keystore. I've only downloaded and imported one certificate, but why are there 160 entries in the keystore.

Comment: Probably, because there were 159 in the truststore your jvm is using. compare both truststores and check that :).

Comment: The code of `installCert` exports the downloaded certificate into a file named `jssecacerts`. I'm pretty sure that the file is generated by my program, as I've deleted the file before running my program.

Comment: ok. Dont check it if you dont want but... It is all that i can do for helping. It doesnt matter how sure you are about the behaviour of InstallCert app. The behaviour is what it is. Check the piece of code of that application, that i have just added to my answer and decide. JSSECACERTS is NOT generated from empty file. Check it and compare both files and lets see if finally you get convinced     :)

Comment: Please check line `147` of `installCert`: `OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jssecacerts");`, it doesn't reuse the variable `file`.

Comment: As you prefer... check the whole application code and not just that line... It does not use the file variable?? And what about ks file?? anyway, i cant help you if you dont wnat the help. Good luck. Here you can read about the behaviour of the app: http://www.dekho.com.au/help/32/default.htm?turl=Documents%2Faddingacertificateintothejavacertificatestore.htm

Comment: As you said, I've read the doc, and check the last sentence of the 6th section: `The imported certificates get added to a keystore named “jssecacerts” in the current directory (i.e., C:\temp\installcerts)`

Comment: My friend. Lets be clear: InstallCert, creates C:/temp/jssecacerts; true. But this file is a copy of cacerts file placed on JaVA_HOME/jre/security/lib. After copy it, Install cert adds your certificate. Anyway, please, before going on with the complains, please check both files with the tool i suggested and see, that the only diference is that jssecacerts has your certificate and cacerts doesnt

Comment: Okay, now I see, the `jssecacerts` generated by `InstallCert` contains all the certificates in the truststore of JRE + the one that it has downloaded. Thank you!